# Double citation problem with apacite and BibTeX

Tags: bibtex

When I attempt to insert an APA citation like so:

```
\cite[5.]{law1966money}
```

With the BibTeX entry looking like this:

```
@book{law1966money,
title={Money and trade considered},
author={Law, John},
year={1966},
publisher={AM Kelley}
}
```

It inserts a double citation into the document:

[image]

I'm using BibTeX and the apacite package in TeXStudio, after the Compile->Bibliography->Compile->Compile chain of events to get all the references loaded, and my code looks like this (my bibliography is in `references.bib` in the same folder):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{setspace} % Double-space
\usepackage{csquotes} % Block quotes
\usepackage{apacite} % APA citation style

\bibliographystyle{apa}
\doublespacing
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\maketitle

% Document stuff...
Test cite \cite[5.]{law1966money}

\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think that apa.bst is meant to be used together with apacite. Try `\bibliographystyle{apacite}` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package `apacite` requires the bibstyle `apacite` rather than `apa`.  Change the line

```
  \bibliographystyle{apa}
```

to

```
  \bibliographystyle{apacite}
```

and the result will be `Test cite (Law, 1966, 5.)`, as it should be